# How to put label outside gauge JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have one issues, i create custom gauge, but outside this gauge i wanna show the label with value.

For gauge creating i use: gauge.min.js

So i want to put outside gauge values with numbers of %.

My code:

html:

```
  <canvas id="gauge"></canvas>
            <span id="gauge1-txt"></span>
            <div class="gaugeData">   
                <h1>Efficency</h1>
                <h1 id="eff"></h1>
                <input type="number" id="number" />
            </div>
            <button onclick="changeData()">test</button>
```

JS:

```
let canvas = document.getElementById('gauge');
let context = canvas.getContext('2d');
let lowerBadLimit = 50;
let loweAcceptLimit = 70;
let lowerGoodLimit = 85;
let nominalValue = 100;
let upperGoodLimit = 110;
let upperAcceptLimit = 120;
let upperBaadLimit = 150;
var globalValues = [];
var gaugeStart = 0;
var gaugeEnd = 100;
var inputValue = 150;
var poinenetValue = 0;


function drawGaugeSegment(canvas, context, x, y, beginPercent, endPercent, color) {
    let beginAngle = Math.PI + (Math.PI * (beginPercent / 100));
    let endAngle = 0 - (Math.PI * (1 - endPercent / 100));

    context.strokeStyle = color;
    context.lineWidth = 60;

    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(x, y, 170, beginAngle, endAngle);
    context.stroke();
}

function drawNeedle(canvas, context, x, y, percent, color) {
    context.fillStyle = color;
    context.translate(x, y);
    context.rotate(Math.PI * percent / 100 - Math.PI / 2);

    let needleWidth = 15;
    let needleLength = 130;

    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(0, 0, needleWidth / 2, 0, Math.PI);
    context.moveTo(0 - needleWidth / 2, 0);
    context.lineTo(0, 0 - needleLength);
    context.lineTo(needleWidth / 2, 0);
    context.lineTo(0 - needleWidth / 2, 0)
    context.fill();

}


function drawGauge(canvas, context, x, y) {
    drawGaugeSegment(canvas, context, x, y, gaugeStart, globalValues[0] - 1, '#FF6363');
    drawGaugeSegment(canvas, context, x, y, globalValues[0], globalValues[1] - 1, '#FEF567');
    drawGaugeSegment(canvas, context, x, y, globalValues[1], globalValues[2] - 1, '#70FE67');
    drawGaugeSegment(canvas, context, x, y, globalValues[2], globalValues[3] - 1, '#70FE67');
    drawGaugeSegment(canvas, context, x, y, globalValues[3], globalValues[4] - 1, '#FEF567');
    drawGaugeSegment(canvas, context, x, y, globalValues[4], gaugeEnd, '#FF6363');

    drawNeedle(canvas, context, x, y, poinenetValue, '#fff');
}

function gaugeCalc() {
    var valueRange = upperBaadLimit - lowerBadLimit;
    var gaugeRange = gaugeEnd - gaugeStart;
    var scale = gaugeRange / valueRange;
    var gaugeZone1 = (loweAcceptLimit - lowerBadLimit) * scale;
    var gaugeZone2 = (lowerGoodLimit - lowerBadLimit) * scale;
    var gaugeZone3 = (nominalValue - lowerBadLimit) * scale;
    var gaugeZone4 = (upperGoodLimit - lowerBadLimit) * scale;
    var gaugeZone5 = (upperAcceptLimit - lowerBadLimit) * scale;

    var values = [gaugeZone1, gaugeZone2, gaugeZone3, gaugeZone4, gaugeZone5];

    globalValues = values;

var convertedValue = (getValue() - lowerBadLimit) * scale;

            if (convertedValue < gaugeStart) {
                poinenetValue = gaugeStart;
                console.log(poinenetValue);
            } else if (convertedValue > gaugeEnd) {
                poinenetValue = gaugeEnd;
                console.log(poinenetValue);
            } else {
                poinenetValue = convertedValue;
                console.log(poinenetValue);

            }
        }

function getValue(val) {
            val = $('#number').val();
            return val;
        }

function changeData() {
            gaugeCalc();
            draw()
            changeEffValue()
        }

function changeEffValue() {
            document.getElementById('eff').innerHTML = getValue() + ' %';
        }


 function draw() {
            canvas.width = 550;
            canvas.height = 250;
            drawGauge(canvas, context, 260, 225);
        }


        gaugeCalc()
        draw();
```

Some example, now i have:

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lX5XV.png)

I want to have values out side like this:

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PgL3J.png)

So as you can see, at my code, i have not standart possibility to add label out side gauge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can include text directly in a canvas (see [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Drawing_text) ).

For example in `drawGaugeSegment` you already have the center of your gauge, the angle, all you need is some math.

Here i took `215` as the radius of the circle where to display the text, the `- 6` and `+ 3` are fixed little adjustments because `fillText`'s x/y are a corner of the text, not the center (values might change depending on font size / length of text)

that gives `context.fillText(endPercent, x - 6 + parseInt(Math.cos(endAngle) * 215), y + 3 + parseInt(Math.sin(endAngle) * 215));`

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById('gauge');
let context = canvas.getContext('2d');
let lowerBadLimit = 50;
let loweAcceptLimit = 70;
let lowerGoodLimit = 85;
let nominalValue = 100;
let upperGoodLimit = 110;
let upperAcceptLimit = 120;
let upperBaadLimit = 150;
var globalValues = [];
var gaugeStart = 0;
var gaugeEnd = 100;
var inputValue = 150;
var poinenetValue = 0;


function drawGaugeSegment(canvas, context, x, y, beginPercent, endPercent, color, text) {
    let beginAngle = Math.PI + (Math.PI * (beginPercent / 100));
    let endAngle = 0 - (Math.PI * (1 - endPercent / 100));

    context.strokeStyle = color;
    context.lineWidth = 60;

    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(x, y, 170, beginAngle, endAngle);
    context.stroke();
    
    context.fillText(text, x - 6 + parseInt(Math.cos(endAngle) * 215), y + 3 + parseInt(Math.sin(endAngle) * 215));
}

function drawNeedle(canvas, context, x, y, percent, color) {
    context.fillStyle = color;
    context.translate(x, y);
    context.rotate(Math.PI * percent / 100 - Math.PI / 2);

    let needleWidth = 15;
    let needleLength = 130;

    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(0, 0, needleWidth / 2, 0, Math.PI);
    context.moveTo(0 - needleWidth / 2, 0);
    context.lineTo(0, 0 - needleLength);
    context.lineTo(needleWidth / 2, 0);
    context.lineTo(0 - needleWidth / 2, 0)
    context.fill();

}


function drawGauge(canvas, context, x, y) {
    drawGaugeSegment(canvas, context, x, y, gaugeStart, globalValues[0] - 1, '#FF6363', 'test');
    drawGaugeSegment(canvas, context, x, y, globalValues[0], globalValues[1] - 1, '#FEF567', globalValues[1]);
    drawGaugeSegment(canvas, context, x, y, globalValues[1], globalValues[2] - 1, '#70FE67', globalValues[2]);
    drawGaugeSegment(canvas, context, x, y, globalValues[2], globalValues[3] - 1, '#70FE67', globalValues[3]);
    drawGaugeSegment(canvas, context, x, y, globalValues[3], globalValues[4] - 1, '#FEF567', globalValues[4]);
    drawGaugeSegment(canvas, context, x, y, globalValues[4], gaugeEnd, '#FF6363', gaugeEnd);

    drawNeedle(canvas, context, x, y, poinenetValue, '#fff');
}

function gaugeCalc() {
    var valueRange = upperBaadLimit - lowerBadLimit;
    var gaugeRange = gaugeEnd - gaugeStart;
    var scale = gaugeRange / valueRange;
    var gaugeZone1 = (loweAcceptLimit - lowerBadLimit) * scale;
    var gaugeZone2 = (lowerGoodLimit - lowerBadLimit) * scale;
    var gaugeZone3 = (nominalValue - lowerBadLimit) * scale;
    var gaugeZone4 = (upperGoodLimit - lowerBadLimit) * scale;
    var gaugeZone5 = (upperAcceptLimit - lowerBadLimit) * scale;

    var values = [gaugeZone1, gaugeZone2, gaugeZone3, gaugeZone4, gaugeZone5];

    globalValues = values;

var convertedValue = (getValue() - lowerBadLimit) * scale;

            if (convertedValue < gaugeStart) {
                poinenetValue = gaugeStart;
                console.log(poinenetValue);
            } else if (convertedValue > gaugeEnd) {
                poinenetValue = gaugeEnd;
                console.log(poinenetValue);
            } else {
                poinenetValue = convertedValue;
                console.log(poinenetValue);

            }
        }

function getValue(val) {
            val = $('#number').val();
            return val;
        }

function changeData() {
            gaugeCalc();
            draw()
            changeEffValue()
        }

function changeEffValue() {
            document.getElementById('eff').innerHTML = getValue() + ' %';
        }


 function draw() {
            canvas.width = 550;
            canvas.height = 250;
            drawGauge(canvas, context, 260, 225);
        }


        gaugeCalc()
        draw();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="gauge"></canvas>
            <span id="gauge1-txt"></span>
            <div class="gaugeData">   
                <h1>Efficency</h1>
                <h1 id="eff"></h1>
                <input type="number" id="number" />
            </div>
            <button onclick="changeData()">test</button>
```

**EDIT** to customize the values, you can simply add a `text` parameter to display instead of the percent

Comment: thanks, for answer, but if i want to put another values? ex(10,50,90,120,150)

Comment: edited so that you can use a custom text on `drawGaugeSegment` function call